# Clean tainted canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, openlayers, html2canvas

Is it possible to clean a tainted canvas?

I have an Openlayers map where user can add layer with CORS restriction. I can't bypass the cors by my proxy config and crossOrigin='anonymus' is not an option.

What I need, it's to be able to remove the "*bad*" layer and let the user produces the map image.

So I try to:

- Remove the layer who can't be printed
- Try to sync the map
- Try to print

But I always get the cors error. How can I make my map *great again* without refreshing the browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no way to *clean* a tainted canvas.
Once tainted, it will remain tainted for its whole life.

Not only this, but also drawing this canvas on a second canvas will taint that second canvas too. Even if that canvas has been completely cleared.

So, the only way for you, is to start again from a new canvas element, and to filter out the bad layers before they are drawn.

Comment: :'( Very bad behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property crossOrigin in the source of added layer so you can give it the value `crossOrigin: "Anonymous"` as the following sample

```
var basemap = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
            ratio: 1,
            params: {},
            crossOrigin: "Anonymous",
            url: "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer"
        })
   })
```

I hope this will fit

Comment: Like I said in my question: "... crossOrigin='anonymus' is not an option."